# Laravel Eloquent Relationship Sub-Relationship?

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-5.1

I have an Offer class with the following relationship:

```
class Offer extends Model
{
    public function releases()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Release');
    }
}
```

The Release class has this relationship:

```
class Release extends Model
{
    public function artist()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Artist');
    }
}
```

What is the simplest way of amending

```
   App\Offer::with('releases')->get();
```

So as to also get Artist information in each release?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You can do this by:

```
App\Offer::with('releases.artist')->get();
```

You can look at: http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/eloquent-relationships#querying-relations for more information.

If you have multiple releations you can query them by doing:

```
App\Offer::with(['releases.artist', 'releases.albums'])->get();
```

When you scrolldown a bit you see

```
// Retrieve all posts that have at least one comment with votes...
$posts = Post::has('comments.votes')->get();
```

Remember the "dot" notations is a standard convention of Laravel. For example loading a view:

```
view('folder.viewfile');
```

The same applies to eloquents nested relationships.

Comment: Oh, beautiful, I should have known that Laravel would be able to do it, and in such a simple and elegant way. Thanks for the very speedy answer, will accept as soon as possible!

Comment: What if I also have releases.albums?
Would I do App\Ofer::with('releases.artist')->with('releases.albums')->get();

Comment: @ajameswolf I've updated my answer. You can do that by passing an array of values.

Answer (score 0):

```
OrderProduct::with(
                array(
                    'product' => function ($query) {
                        $query->select('id', 'store_id', 'en_name', 'bn_name', 'image')->with(
                            array(
                                'store' => function ($q) {
                                    $q->select('id');
                                }
                            )
                        );
                    }
                )
            )->where('order_id', $order->id)->get(),
```